# Sed's "+" quantifier does not seem to match anything

Tags: sed

I have a file sedTest.txt with content:

```
sdjalsh ABC 123 ashfaladhs
ldjkasf ABC 234 dadas afsf
dafsafs ABC 876 asf dasfaf
```

I want to output just those `123`, `234`, `876`.

I can manage that using

```
cat sedTest.txt | sed s"/.*ABC \([0-9]+\).*/\1/"
```

I used it that way, because typically there is grep instead of cat, in this case it might be

```
grep ABC sedTest.txt | sed s"/.*ABC \([0-9]+\).*/\1/"
```

which makes not really sense here, but this is typical use with logs.

I'm wondering: why is using `[0-9]+` not working? I'd expect the same result as for `[0-9]*`, but it seems that nothing is replaced (and unchanged content is printed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is an ERE metacharacter, sed uses BREs by default. Either use `sed -E ... + ...` or `sed ... \+ ...` to enable `+`s ERE property, e.g.

```
grep 'ABC' sedTest.txt | sed -E 's/ABC ([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

and note that you no longer need to escape the parens to enable their ERE metacharacter properties when you use `-E` and the leading `.*` was doing nothing useful so I got rid of it. Also, you don't need grep+sed, this will do:

```
sed -E -n 's/ABC ([0-9]+).*/\1/p' sedTest.txt
```

but more importantly you should really be using:

```
awk '$2=="ABC"{print $3}' sedTest.txt
```

instead for clarity, simplicity, robustness, portability, etc.

Always note that you should enclose scripts (sed, awk, grep, whatever) in single quotes (`'`), not double (`"`) unless you enjoy surprises when the shell decides to interpret some values in your script before your tool sees them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Can you add some links describing EREs/BREs in more detail (or something else for a reference).  After your post I noticed this acronym in sed manual page...

Comment: No, just google them. Understanding BREs/EREs is fundamental to writing shell scripts, adding links for those would be like adding links to describe "if" and "then".