# Why is my sed script not returning the data I expect?

Tags: sed

I've written a sed script to pull the value of a field out of the multi-line output of a command, but it's not working, and I can't see what is wrong.

```
$ cf target | sed -e 's/space:\s+\(\S+\).*/\1/p'
api endpoint:   https://api.sys.gn01.pcf.my.com
api version:    2.112.0
user:           userid
org:            cart-creation
space:          stage
```

I am expecting to see the value `stage`, but when I use the `-n` option, I am seeing no output at all. I took out the `-n` above just to show what the output from my command looks like.

Comment: `+` is part of extended regular expressions (ERE). Sed defaults to basic regular expressions (BRE), which don't have that quantifier. GNU sed offers it as an extension, but it has to be escaped: `\+`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed +/\* not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721274/sed-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Seems easier to do `awk '$1 == "space:" { print $2}'`

Comment: @BenjaminW., in this case it is needed, as OP wants to match it so it *can* be thrown away. Perhaps all that is needed is `sed -n 's/^space:[[:blank:]]\+//p'`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't as familiar with awk, but you're right, that's super easy, and I'll use it.

Comment: @glennjackman Oh, right! Deleting...

Answer (score 0):

You got a reasonable awk answer in the comments but consider this approach instead:

```
$ awk '{t=$0; sub(/:.*/,"",t); sub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,""); f[t]=$0} END{print f["space"]}' file
stage

$ awk '{t=$0; sub(/:.*/,"",t); sub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,""); f[t]=$0} END{print f["api version"]}' file
2.112.0

$ awk '{t=$0; sub(/:.*/,"",t); sub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,""); f[t]=$0}
    END{print f["space"], f["org"], f["api version"]}' file
stage cart-creation 2.112.0

$ awk -v n='space' '{t=$0; sub(/:.*/,"",t); sub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,""); f[t]=$0} END{print f[n]}' file
stage
```

as it allows you to print any values(s) you like in any order just by their name.